# Is everything an object in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

when we query all_objects table we get object_type as table,index,cluster.

Can we consider all those an objects? what are object types then? I am confused. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular corner of Oracle jargon (`all_objects.object_type`) *an object* doesn't refer to [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) but a general [entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity).

The values of `object_type` columns are objects in the same fashion than a fork, a knife or a spoon are objects too.

However Oracle [supports OOP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjint.htm#ADOBJ001) with abstract data types (ADT). If an object is ADT then the value of `all_objects.object_type` is `type`.

Don't be worried if you're still confused. It takes it's time ...

Comment: Even the term "entity" is potentially confusing because entities usually refer to the real-world "entities" that are modelled in a data model. I usually refer to them as "schema objects".